# Subdomain linked to a subdirectory?

Tags: .htaccess, indexing, subdomain, subdirectory

I'm trying to set up my own cloud network and just got it to work the way I want it to, but I was hoping to linking it to a domain I own over at Godaddy. I want to use a subdomain for the cloud-thingy, but I don't want to link it to the ip alone. I'd rather link it to i.e "11.222.333.44/storage", instead of just "11.222.333.44" so I can still host a website at my domain's root

Comment: I think you can get a better answer at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ or http://serverfault.com/ - Reading your question I guess you have changed the dns so the subdomain `sub.example.com` links to the same server as `www.example.com` or `example.com`. How to configure Apache to distinguish those two subdomains is not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you need a Name-based Virtual Host, [read the Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).